# How to set up importmap-rails in Rails 7 engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, import-maps, ruby-on-rails-7

I have opened an issue in the importmap-rails gem github repository [here](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/issues/58) about this but thought I'd throw the question out here in case anyone might have a workaround

This is what I have discovered so far

A new engine with Rails 7 alpha 2 or Rails 7.0, generated using `rails plugin new custom_page --mountable --full` generates a new engine that includes the importmap-rails gem in the bundled gems but there is no ability to use it. Adding `spec.add_dependency 'importmap-rails'` to the enginename.gemspec makes no difference, nor does adding a `require importmap-rails` to engine.rb. There is no importmap executable in the bin directory.
A call to `bundle info importmap-rails`
Produces a promising result showing that the gem is installed by default

```
* importmap-rails (0.8.1)
    Summary: Use ESM with importmap to manage modern JavaScript in Rails without transpiling or bundling.
    Homepage: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
    Source Code: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
    Path: /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@custom_page/gems/importmap-rails-0.8.1
```

A call to `rails --tasks` shows

```
rails app:importmap:install # Setup Importmap for the app
```

But I believe this is coming from the test application generated by the --full option rather than being available to the rails command for the engine.
I was expecting to see the same without app: prefix
A call to this task resolves to a template error as shown

```
rails app:importmap:install
```

> Don't know how to build task 'app:template' (See the list of available
> tasks with `rails --tasks`) Did you mean?  app:tmp:create

If there is a workaround solution to this I'd be grateful to hear it and I'm sure others will too. The reason for me wanting this is that I totally failed to introduced webpacker in a rails 6.1.4 engine and I was hoping this was going to be my, much improved, solution

**Update in response to Alex**

Running `bin/importmap json` within the engine directory results in

importmap-rails-1.2.1/lib/importmap/commands.rb:63:in `json': undefined method` join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
require Rails.root.join("config/environment")
                  ^^^^^
from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@custom_page/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@custom_page/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@custom_page/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@custom_page/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
from /home/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@custom_page/gems/importmap-rails-1.2.1/lib/importmap/commands.rb:147:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
from <internal:/home/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
from bin/importmap:24:in `<main>'
```

This engine functionality is not in an app yet

There are no importmap error messages in my logs, searched for "Importmap skipped missing path" and "skipped" and "importmap", the last did throw up errors from an earlier bug but nothing since that bug was resolved

I have a standard assets setup, I do have a feature that updates css files which may be what you are thinking of.

I have no compiled assets and all files are named import and import.rb in the singular

The following code in my application.js is as follows

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
```

my manifest

```
//= link_directory ../stylesheets/ccs_cms/custom_page .css
//= link_tree ../javascripts/ccs_cms/custom_page .js
//= link_tree ../javascripts/new_ckeditor
//= link ccs_cms/custom_page/jqtree.css
//= link ccs_cms/custom_page/public.css
```

my application.js looks like

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails

//= require ccs_cms/custom_page/jquery-3.6.0.min
//= require ccs_cms/custom_page/jquery-ui.min
//= require ccs_cms/custom_page/tree.jquery
//= require ccs_cms/custom_page/sortable
//= require ccs_cms/custom_page/nested_fields/addFields
//= require_tree .

//require("./nested-forms/addFields");
//require("./nested-forms/removeFields");

// do some javascript
document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "Hi!, i'm your engine";
console.log("hi, again");
```

importmap.rb contains the following

```
# my_engine/config/importmap.rb

# NOTE: this pin works because `my_engine/app/assets/javascripts
#       is in the `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`
pin "ccs_cms/custom_page/application"
```

The following is generated in the head

```
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
  }
}</script>
```

along with

```
<script type="module">import "application"</script>

<script type="module">import "ccs_cms/custom_page/application"</script>
```

A further update: I do see the hi again message in the console so the `console.log("hi, again");` works but the `document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "Hi!, i'm your engine";` has no effect

Finally, adding

```
  initializer :append_importmap_paths do |app|
    app.config.importmap.paths << root.join("config/importmap.rb")
  end
```

to the engine.rb resolved the last piece of the jigsaw

Comment: Actually, you don't have `app:template`, but you should have `app:app:template`. My workaround is to create an alias rake task to bypass this error. 

in your rake file :
`desc 'Alias to app:app:template'
task template: :environment do
  Rake::Task['app:app:template'].invoke
end`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to use the install task to set up importmaps. All it does is a few copy paste operations and it doesn't really help with the engine set up anyway.

Add importmaps to engine's gemspec file:

```
# my_engine/my_engine.gemspec

spec.add_dependency "importmap-rails"
```

Update *engine.rb*:

```
# my_engine/lib/my_engine/engine.rb

require "importmap-rails"

module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    
    initializer "my-engine.importmap", before: "importmap" do |app|
      # NOTE: this will add pins from this engine to the main app
      # https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#composing-import-maps
      app.config.importmap.paths << root.join("config/importmap.rb")

      # NOTE: something about cache; I did not look into it.
      # https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#sweeping-the-cache-in-development-and-test
      app.config.importmap.cache_sweepers << root.join("app/assets/javascripts")
    end

    # NOTE: add engine manifest to precompile assets in production
    initializer "my-engine.assets" do |app|
      app.config.assets.precompile += %w[my_engine_manifest]
    end
  end
end
```

Update assets manifest:

```js
# my_engine/app/assets/config/my_engine_manifest.js

//= link_tree ../javascripts/my_engine .js
```

Add javascript entry point for our engine, if needed. Pins will be available without this file.

```js
# my_engine/app/assets/javascripts/my_engine/application.js

// do some javascript
document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "hi, i'm your engine";
console.log("hi, again");
```

Update engine's layout:

```html
# my_engine/app/views/layouts/my_engine/application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--
      NOTE: This loads/imports main app `application.js` and all the pins from
            the main app and from the engine (because we set it up in the engine.rb).
    -->
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

    <!--
      NOTE: To add engine's javascript functionality we have to load the
            entrypoint here or `import` it in the main app `application.js`
    -->
    <%= javascript_import_module_tag "my_engine/application" %>
  </head>
  <body> <%= yield %> </body>
</html>
```

Create *importmap.rb* and pin `my_engine/application`, this name has to match with `javascript_import_module_tag`. It cannot clash with any other name in the main app, so you can't just use `application`:

```
# my_engine/config/importmap.rb

# NOTE: this pin works because `my_engine/app/assets/javascripts
#       is in the `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`
pin "my_engine/application"
```

Some extras to test the setup:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/"
end

# my_engine/config/routes.rb
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  get "home", to: "homes#index"
end

# my_engine/app/controllers/my_engine/homes_controller.rb
module MyEngine
  class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def index; end
  end
end

# my_engine/app/views/my_engine/homes/index.html.erb
<h1>Home</h1>
```

At this point you should have this in your rendered layout's `<head>` tag, among other things:

```html
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-66ce7505c61e3e4910ff16e7c220e1fbfb39251cd82e4bab8d325b3aae987cf9.js",
    "my_engine/application": "/assets/my_engine/application-31ce493e8376b4c20703a50f38d419ae309ffe410b7ab7fec47440e02eef08a8.js",
  }
}</script>

<script type="module">import "application"</script>
<script type="module">import "my_engine/application"</script>
```

`H1` tag should change to `<h1>hi, i'm your engine</h1>` on reload.

Additional importmaps can be added manually with https://generator.jspm.io/.

For bonus points, `bin/importmap` can be customized to work inside the engine. Create a new `importmap` file inside *bin* directory.

```rb
# my_engine/bin/importmap

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# NOTE: don't forget to `chmod u+x bin/importmap` to make it executable.

# make sure we are loading the correct versions of things
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] ||= File.expand_path("../Gemfile", __dir__)
require "bundler/setup" if File.exist?(ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"])

# NOTE: importmap requires some rails goodness that we don't have in the engine,
#       because we don't have `config/application.rb` that loads the environment.
require "rails"

# importmap-rails is not loaded automatically
require "importmap-rails"

# the actual command runner
require "importmap/commands"
```

Run from inside the engine directory:

```bash
$ bin/importmap pin react  
Pinning "react" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:react@18.1.0/index.js

$ cat config/importmap.rb 
pin "my_engine/application"
pin "react", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:react@18.1.0/index.js"
```

I haven't tested it too much, so any feedback would be welcome. Restart the server if something doesn't show up, I don't know how reloading behaves with all this.

Comment: Thank you so much for yet another detailed answer. I'll check this out soon and if it works for me I'll let you know

Comment: Instead of using both `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` and `<%= javascript_import_module_tag "my_engine/application" %>`, you can use a single `<%= javascript_importmap_tags "my_engine/application" %>`

Comment: Revisiting this now and 2 issues, first is that in the bin/importmap file the `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` declaration must appear as the first line in the file rather than the file name comment, with this change `bin/importmap pin react` works the second issue is that the `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` generates an empty import set i.e. `"imports": { }` No idea why, I am setting this up now to enable me to use stimulus for a add and remove fields in a fieldset feature I'm working on. I have yet to check if stimulus will work but assume that it won't unless the imports set is populated.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have updated my question

Comment: @jamesc did you add `app.config.importmap.paths << root.join("config/importmap.rb")`. you can check your importmap from the console: `Rails.application.importmap` (you should have some @packages and @directories) and see what it generates: `puts Rails.application.importmap.to_json(resolver: helper)`.

Comment: @jamesc also you need to have importmaps installed in your test app or main app (probably).

Comment: Awesome, adding `app.config.importmap.paths << root.join("config/importmap.rb")` to an initializer in the engine sorted out my issues, thank you again, if you are ever in Leeds I'll have to buy you a pint. No need to add importmap to the dummy test app

Answer (score 3):

I fall back to the old school Javascript include in the html.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

Well it definitely works on all browser instead of figuring out if the browser supports the feature that I might use later.

I have full control which page to put too... but that might not be what you want...