# Specifying Paths for View Components in a Gem Utilizing Tailwind CSS in `tailwind.config.js`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, view-components

I'm developing a gem that acts as a library of view components integrated with Tailwind CSS. In this project, there's a crucial `tailwind.config.js` file where I specify the paths for building the tags used in the components. Here's a sample configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/views/**/*.html.erb',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.css',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/components/**/*.rb'
  ]
}
```

My question revolves around determining the correct path to include for the gem's view components. Would it be something like `my_gem/app/components/**/*.rb`?

Additionally, I'm curious if there's a method to automate the addition of this path information upon installing the gem?

Answer (score 1):

You could merge your gem config with main app config, just need to fix relative paths:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  // ...
}

const path = require('path');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const gemName = "my_gem";
const gemPath = execSync(`bin/bundle show ${gemName}`, { encoding: 'utf-8' }).trim();
const gemConfig = require(path.resolve(gemPath, 'tailwind.config.js'));

gemConfig.content.forEach(contentPath => {
  const absolutePath = path.resolve(gemPath, contentPath);
  module.exports.content.push(absolutePath);
});
```

Based on this answer by @Torsten:
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/74737193/207090*

Comment: Here is a gem using it : https://github.com/cmer/ultimate_turbo_modal-rails/issues/8. You can see how to add it to your tailwind exports.content in its README

Answer (score 0):

`Gem.loaded_specs['your_gem_name'].full_gem_path` sounds like a good starting point to investigate into

The idea is to be able to read `process.env.YOUR_GEM_COMPONENTS_PATH` within tailwind.config.js, so there might be some tweaking to do around it.

```
ENV['YOUR_GEM_COMPONENTS_PATH'] = Rails.root.join(
  Gem.loaded_specs['your_gem_name'].full_gem_path,
  "app", "components"
)
```

vite_rails provides a similar use case ([engine link](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vite_ruby/tree/main/examples/rails/example_engine)), this [is how it is defined](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vite_ruby/blob/main/examples/rails/config/vite.rb) in the parent app, and [how it is consumed](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vite_ruby/blob/main/examples/rails/vite.config.ts#L32) in the vite config

Comment: I like the approach but it didn't work. The tailwind CLI run without intervention of the rails app, so the env var isn't defined to process.env.

Comment: I wasn't sure to accurately respond to your answer; sounds like it matches your issue. I'm interested to find a way to make such thing work; will update if anything pop up